# Rails render return do not stop execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

Hi inmy app I has such a situation:

in `some_controller.rb` I has a code aout this:

```
def start
  method1(param)
  ....
  if some_case
    render json: {ok: "ok"}
  end
end

def method1
  ...
  if some_case
    render json: {error: "Some error"}
    return
  end
end
```

The thing is when it's time to render a json with error, I get a `double render` error. It advices me to use `render .. and return`. I've tried even that, and still get this error.
Is this because `render` do not breaks execution itself, but just returns smth to a caller method? If it's so, what can I do in my case? The thing is `method1` is actually a big method and I surely want it to be separateed from `start` method. And in case there are no reasons to render an error there, I want an execution of `start` to be continued.

Thanx!

Comment: Your `return` applies only to the method it's in (`method1`). Then control returns to `start` and proceeds with the rest of the code. Including the second render. You can use a before filter, as MikDiet suggested.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So, that's I thought about. Here `return` works like a usual `return` in other languages and don't mean to stop further execution. Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using filter instead. This works:

```
before_action :method1, only: :start
def start
  ....
  if some_case
    render json: {ok: "ok"}
  end
end

def method1
  ...
  if some_case
    render json: {error: "Some error"}
    return
  end
end
```

When render occurs in filter, it does not run action itself then, so no double render occurs.

Comment: Yep, it sound like a solution. Don't know why I didn't thought about filters. And just for getting smarter: how could I hadle the same situation in case I need to call `method1` in the middle of `start`? Return 0 (or thms like this) or error message from `method1` and process this responce in `start`?

Comment: @Ngoral: In this case, your best bet is to extract rendering from `method1`, so that it only does... whatever it does now besides rendering :) You can have it return a boolean. If it returns true, parent method continues. If it returns false, parent method renders error and stops

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So, somehow like I've expected.
Thanx again=)

Answer (score -2):

Use this code

```
def method1
  if some_case
    render json: {error: "Some error", status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Comment: How is it going to prevent double render problem?